# Linksys Router not working properly

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I have a Linksys WRT54GH wireless router that I bought 3 years ago. When I try to connect to the internet, SOMETIMES it shows full signal but limited conectivity(with that annoying yellow triangle) However, when I remove the ethernet cable from the wireless router and plug it directly in the laptop (with the other end connected to the modem of course) I get proper internet connection. 

1. What could be wrong with my router? 

2. How can I find out what's the matter with it?
 I also tried to reset the router, update it's firmware and reconfigure. But still, the problem persists.

Comment: Are you trying to connect wirelessly?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to connect wirelessly.

Comment: It **sounds** like you have a cable modem providing the internet connection, and that the first device you connected the modem to was the laptop, and not the router.  This is important to mention, because cable modems get the MAC address of the first device they are connected to, the first time they are powered on.  From that point, the cable modem only provides internet connectivity to that specific MAC address... until the modem is powered down.  Have you tried connecting the modem to the router, then power cycling the modem?

Comment: It seems like you are not getting internet to your router.  Routers are not interchangeable with modems.  Modems are what provide internet connection from your ISP (Internet Service Provider), routers connect devices wired or wirelessly.  However, many routers have a built-in modem which is why many people do not learn the proper distinction (this was my case).  What type of ISP do you have, Comcast, DSL, dial-up?  Also, usually on modem-routers, there is a light that signifies if the modem-router has an internet connection.  Is this light on?

Comment: @Josh, I have cable connection. Bon, Yes I did try that. MY ISP engineer kept saying that he could ping my modem successfully and that there is no issue with the modem.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you might have your router plugged in wrong.

This is typically how a home network is wired (for most typical users):

```
 Internet
   ^
   |
   v
/-------\
| Modem |-----\     /-----LAN-----\
\-------/   /-------------\     /--------\
            | W  |  L     |     | Laptop |
            | A  |  A     |  or \--------/
            | N  |  N     |            |
            |             | )) Wifi )) *
            | Router      |
            \-------------/
```

Power off the cable modem and sure that your modem is plugged into the WAN port on the router and that the router is configured on the WAN facing side in accordance with your ISP's needs (usually DHCP, for cable operators). You should then set the router up to provide it's own DHCP to the LAN side of the router (unless you are using a separate DHCP server). Power up the modem so that it can connect and the router can get it's address from the ISP.

<strike>If you are still having difficulty, call your ISP's technical support line. They are usually pretty good about getting basic stuff fixed.</strike>

**Edit:**
I did a little more digging and found a user on the Linksys support forum complaining about randomly getting disconnected from the router. There was a solution poster [here](http://community.linksys.com/t5/Wireless-Routers/WRT54GH-disconnects-about-10-12-times-per-hour/m-p/355925?comm_cc=HSus&comm_lang=en#M188252):

1. Disable UPnP
2. Under wireless settings: Set Beacon Interval 75, RTS and Fragmentaion threshold 2304
3. Try setting channel to 1 or 11
4. Save Settings
5. Connect and try again.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have everything connected just as you mentioned. I get proper connectivity via my wireless router. However, often I loose connectivity even when the SSID's signal strength is great. Then I just remove the wireless router from the network. Connect just the modem and my laptop, it works fine. So why this frequent disconnection? 
My ISP engineer kept saying that he could ping my modem successfully and that there is no issue with the modem. He said that it's a router issue and that they cant really help.

Comment: @Shivaji_Vidhale See my edited answer for some info I found, since it's an intermittent thing.